# WKWebViewのデリゲート設定でクラッシュ

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Object-Cで開発しております。
古いプロジェクトを現環境に合わせるための対応を行っております。

UIWebViewを使用していた個所をWKWebViewに差し替え作業を行っております。

// ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface HoneyShopViewController : UIViewController<WKNavigationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet    WKWebView          *webView;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) MBProgressHUD     *hud;
```

// ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@import GoogleMobileAds;

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GADBannerView *bannerView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.view.backgroundColor   = BODY_COLOR;
    
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    
    [webView.layer setBorderColor:LOG_COLOR.CGColor];
    [webView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    PBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PBAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    _hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithWindow:appDelegate.window];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:_hud];
    
    // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
    self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
        initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
        
    self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
    //self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-4057658985177158~5712178529";
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
    [self addBannerViewToView:self.bannerView];
}

- (void)addBannerViewToView:(UIView *)bannerView {
  bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [self.view addSubview:bannerView];
  [self.view addConstraints:@[
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bannerView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                              multiplier:1
                                constant:0],
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bannerView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                              multiplier:1
                                constant:0]
                                ]];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
    self.title = @"タイトル";
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
    PBDataManager   *manager    = [[[PBDataManager alloc]init]autorelease];
    NSDictionary    *user       = [manager getUserData];
    
    NSString        *urlStr     = HONEY_SHOP_URL;
    NSString        *uid        = [user valueForKey:@"uid"];
    NSString        *platform   = @"ios";
    NSString        *version    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];
    
    [_hud show:YES];
    NSDictionary    *postParams     = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:uid, @"uid",
                                       [manager getToken],@"token",
                                       platform, @"platform",
                                       version, @"version",
                                       nil];
    
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"x-appid" value:@"hogehoge"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:urlStr
                                                      parameters:postParams];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation   = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary    *dict =(NSDictionary *)[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]JSONValue];
        [webView loadHTMLString:[dict objectForKey:@"message"] baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"html_template" ofType:@"html"]];
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Shop Error: %@", error);
        [_hud hide:YES];
    }];
    
    [operation start];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
    if ([navigationAction.request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"inapp"]) {
        if ([[PBStoreManager sharedInstance] canMakePayment]) {
            [_hud show:YES];
        }
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        return;
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(nonnull NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler {
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic] == YES){ 
        NSLog(@"didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");
    }else{
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeRejectProtectionSpace, nil);
    }
}
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
{
    [_hud hide:YES];
}
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error {
   [_hud hide:YES];
}
```

上記のようなコードに修正したのですが、

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
```

で

```
Exception   NSException *   "-[UIWebView setNavigationDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ebe0d0"    0x15e7b0c0
```

というエラーが出てクラッシュしてしまいます。
デリゲートの設定を行わなければクラッシュせず表示されるのですが、イベントの取得が出来ず、WebView内でのボタン反応が取れない状態です。

こちら原因や修正方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 3):

このエラーメッセージ:

```
-[UIWebView setNavigationDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ebe0d0"    0x15e7b0c0
```

は、iOSの実行時処理において、「**`UIWebView`のインスタンス** に`setNavigationDelegate:`というセレクタを送ろうとした時に、そのセレクタがわからない」と言うエラーになったことを表しています。

コード上では、`IBOutlet    WKWebView          *webView;`と、`webView`は`WKWebView`型であるかのように宣言されていますが、実際の実行時には`UIWebView`型のインスタンスが`webView`に入っている、と言う状態だと思われます。

コードを`WKWebView`用のものに修正したものの、storyboard(またはxib)の方は変更できていないのではないでしょうか?

###### UIWebViewの場合

[image: UIWebViewの画像]

###### WKWebViewの場合

[image: WKWebViewの画像]

該当のWebViewがstoryboard上でWKWebViewになっているかを確かめて、なっていなければいったん削除して「Web Kit View」をその位置に貼り付け直してください。

(IBOutlet, IBActionの接続、制約の設定などが消えてしまう可能性があるので、それらも再確認してみてください。)

Comment: xibファイルを修正し、関連付けを正しく行うことで解決いたしました。ありがとうございました。